# Simplest way to extract file name with max minor version via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Assume with following list of snapshots files in a folder

```
app-SNAPSHOT-01.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-02.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-03.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-04.jar
...
app-SNAPSHOT-xy.jar
```

What is the simplest way to extract the latest (max minor version) file name (i.e. app-SNAPSHOT-xy.jar) via `PowerShell` script?

So far I have tried I tried

```
$maxVersion = ls -Filter app-SNAPSHOT-* | sort { [version]($_.Name.split("-")[-1]) } -Descending | select -Index 0
```

but it throws an error Error: `"Version string portion was too short or too long."`

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Santiago Squarzon for the answer

The actual file name is a bit complicated than above example, which come with timestamp

```
#20211128.031305 being timestamp
app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211128.031305-10.jar
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement a solution on your own? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up guys. I tried `$maxVersion = ls -Filter app-SNAPSHOT-* | sort { [version]($_.Name.split("-")[-1]) } -Descending | select -Index 0` but it throws an error  `Error: "Version string
portion was too short or too long."`. I think to use sorting then get the max version, but I am not very keen on powershell functions...

Comment: Please add your code to your question instead of on the comment section

Comment: [1] **_you are splitting the `.Name` property value ... and that includes the _extension_._** use the `.BaseName` prop instead. [*grin*] [2] at no point do you convert the DIGIT STRING into a `[version]` object. ///// [3]plus, of course, there is no reason to be using `[version]` at all. just convert the _numeric strings_ into `[int]` types and compare that. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you a short explanation of why you are getting that exception. See [`Version Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-6.0) for more details.

> All defined components must be integers greater than or equal to 0. The format of the version number is as follows (optional components are shown in square brackets ([ and ]): 
> major.minor[.build[.revision]]

Example:

```
PS /> [version]'1.0.1'                    

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      0      1      -1
```

In this case, you can't cast `[version]` to the numbers because they don't follow the version format. If you want to convert the numbers between the hyphen and the `.jar` extension it would require manipulation and there is no logic we can follow unless you specify so.

If you simply need to sort by the numbers and get the greater one this is how you can do it:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Filter *.jar |
Sort-Object {
    [int][regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=-)\d+(?=\.jar)').Value
} -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

As an example, I created some files which default order look like this:

```
Name
----
app-SNAPSHOT-01.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-01000.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-04.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-19x9.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-630.jar
```

And after sorting (Note that `app-SNAPSHOT-19x9.jar` is the last one because it does not match the `regex` pattern):

```
Name
----
app-SNAPSHOT-01000.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-630.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-04.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-01.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-19x9.jar
```

---

**EDIT**

This is how you would sort the files that have the naming convention shown on your edit, first by `DateTime` and then by version (the numbers between `-` and the `.jar` extension)

```
@'
app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211128.031305-13.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211129.011305-12.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211122.051305-10.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211128.081305-10.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211129.021305-08.jar
'@ -split '\r?\n' | Sort-Object {
    [datetime]::ParseExact(
        [regex]::Match($_, '(?<=-)\d{8}\.\d{6}(?=-)').Value,
        'yyyyMMdd.HHmmss',
        $null
    )       
},
{
    [int][regex]::Match($_, '(?<=-)\d+(?=\.jar)').Value
} -Descending
```

After sorting the result would be:

```
app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211129.021305-08.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211129.011305-12.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211128.081305-10.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211128.031305-13.jar
app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211122.051305-10.jar
```

In the example above, the "newest" file would be `app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211129.021305-08.jar`. Even though `app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211129.011305-12.jar` has a higher version number it has a less recent timestamp than the other one (by 1 hour exactly):

```
[datetime]::ParseExact('20211129.021305', 'yyyyMMdd.HHmmss', $null) -gt
[datetime]::ParseExact('20211129.011305', 'yyyyMMdd.HHmmss', $null) # => True
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback, I didn't know [int][regex] can place before Match and that's how to sort with regular expression. The actual case of the file would be like `app-SNAPSHOT-0.0.2-20211128.031305-10.jar` with `20211128.031305` being timestamp, so I enhanced your method as `[regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=-)\d+\.\d+-\d+(?=\.jar)').Value` and it seems to work, because there is `dot` and `dash` symbol in the matching string so I took out the `[int]` tag

Comment: @Dreamer That's fine but note, if `20211128.031305` is a timestamp, the best approach you could take is to convert it to a `DateTime` object and sort by that. If you're not sure how to do it I can edit my answer.

Comment: It'd be greatly appreciated if you can provide the Datetime solution, I will also extend my question with this detail

Comment: @Dreamer see my edit. Please if this answers your question, consider accepting it.